# How to build an efficient select command across multiples tables in Rails4?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to figure out an efficient ways to select records that have attributes across multiple tables.  Here's the basic setup:

`structure`

- Plants   (fields: id, name_id, location_id, color) (1000 records)
- Names    (fields: id, Common_name) (50 records)
- Location (fields: id, Bed_name) (125 records)

`model`

- Plants - belongs_to Names, belongs_to Location
- Names  - has_many Plants
- Location - has_many Plants

My goal is to output a list of every Rose in the side yard, and display the color, but I am stuck on the select command.  If I get all plants (`p = Plant.all`) I know that I can easily create my output with a statement like `<%= "#{p.name.common_name} in bed #{p.location.bed_name} has a color of #{p.color}" %>`
If I do two joins I'm looking at way more records that I need and a MUCH longer search time.  As an example - I have 67 roses in 16 different beds, however, I only have 3 roses in the side yard.

My gut tells me that I should be able to do something like:
select all plants with the name of Rose, then from this selection select all Roses that are in the side yard.

Can anybody help point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine it all into a single query like this:

```
Plant.joins(:name, :location).where(names: { common_name: "rose" }, locations: { bed_name: "side" })
```

This results in a single SQL query like this:

```
SELECT "plants".* FROM "plants" INNER JOIN "names" ON "names"."id" = "plants"."name_id" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "plants"."location_id" WHERE "names"."common_name" = 'rose' AND "locations"."bed_name" = 'side'
```

Note that you have to use the plural *table names* in the `where` clause, but the singular *association name* in the `joins` clause.

This will run nearly instantaneously even with enormous tables, assuming your tables are properly indexed.

This is a simple example, but you can do fairly complex joins with conditions. Full details can be found in the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

**Edit**

Per @Dan's comment, you can speed this up more by using `includes` to pre-fetch the association data in the join:

```
Plant.includes(:name, :location).where(names: { common_name: "rose" }, locations: { bed_name: "side" })
```

This will load the related records from `names` and `locations` at the same time. `includes` is handy for eliminating (or at least reducing) N+1 queries. It is also smart enough to know when it can retrieve all the data in a single query, and falls back to multiple queries when that makes more sense; you don't have to think about it (although sometimes it can reduce efficiency, so keep an eye on your logs if you think it's reduces performance).

Using `includes` in this case is very efficient, resulting in a single SQL query which includes association data:

```
 SELECT "plants"."id" AS t0_r0, "plants"."color" AS t0_r1, "plants"."name_id" AS t0_r2, "plants"."location_id" AS t0_r3, "plants"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "plants"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "names"."id" AS t1_r0, "names"."common_name" AS t1_r1, "names"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "names"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "locations"."id" AS t2_r0, "locations"."bed_name" AS t2_r1, "locations"."created_at" AS t2_r2, "locations"."updated_at" AS t2_r3 FROM "plants" LEFT OUTER JOIN "names" ON "names"."id" = "plants"."name_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "plants"."location_id" WHERE "names"."common_name" = 'rose' AND "locations"."bed_name" = 'side'
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that nested syntax, but it was exactly what I needed!  My query has gone from 6000ms to 60ms! :)

Comment: you might consider adding `.includes(:name, :location)` to improve performance further. Here is a little further reading on the topic: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/improving-the-performance-of-your-rails-app-with-eager-loading--cms-25018

Comment: Thanks @Dan, much better that way.

Comment: I suppose I could optimize it even more by only querying the required fields, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader for now.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for updating the code, having the includes was helpful, though a little contrary to the way I'd (mis-)understood includes.  As a side note I have discovered a gem call `bullet[link](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet)` that notifies one of N+1 issues and recommends using includes.  It also tells you if you have unused includes.